# Why is JSHint not showing me the filenames?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint

I'm getting the following from the console...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 11.0.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\myProj\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt --gruntfile C:\Projects\dcloud-v2-ui\Gruntfile.js test
Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task


     16 |          })
                     ^ Missing semicolon.
     76 |          })
                     ^ Missing semicolon.
    113 |      })
                 ^ Missing semicolon.

>> 3 errors in 407 files
Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Why is is not showing me the file with the missing semi colons? I notice is is finishing on a 3. Is that related to an error in Grunt or just telling me the 'hinting' failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like this is [a bug in grunt-contrib-jshint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/240). It previously worked as you would expect, but this is a regression in recent versions. Unfortunately the root of the issue doesn't seem to have been identified, and there's surprisingly little activity on the issue.

Comment: this was confirmed by a colleague actually too so thanks for the answer it's not the answer but its right!

Answer (score 4):

The bug in the chosen answer hasn't been fixed yet. The workaround suggested in the issue [thread](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/240) is to use [jshint-stylish](https://github.com/sindresorhus/jshint-stylish) - an external reporter for jshint

The setup for my project is as easy as running `npm install --save-dev jshint-stylish` and adding the following to `options` section of `jshint`:

```
jshint: {
  options: {
    reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
    ...
  },
...
```